# Visual Studio - Code Snippet Error / Not Working AgumentNullException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets, prop, argumentnullexception

Since i tried to add a spécific code snippet, non of my snippets works.
I've tried to repare and uninstal and reinstall Visual Studio but it does not work.

When i write : prop and tabulation i have an Argument null Exception
[Argument Null Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPyn3.png)

Do you have any solution for me please ?

Comment: I've also tried to reset settings

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i've found.

The solution was to remove a snipper folder with an error in the Code Snippet manager.

One of them had a icone in Visual Basic FoldeR.

If you do not find it, the best way is to remove everything and add it again